# In OpenGL is there a way to get a list of all uniforms & attribs used by a shader program?

Tags: opengl, 3d, shader, glsl

I'd like to get a list of all the uniforms & attribs used by a shader program object.  `glGetAttribLocation()` & `glGetUniformLocation()` can be used to map a string to a location, but what I would really like is the list of strings without having to parse the glsl code.

Note: In OpenGL 2.0 `glGetObjectParameteriv()` is replaced by `glGetProgramiv()`.  And the enum is `GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS` & `GL_ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES`.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

*Variables shared between both examples:*

```
GLint i;
GLint count;

GLint size; // size of the variable
GLenum type; // type of the variable (float, vec3 or mat4, etc)

const GLsizei bufSize = 16; // maximum name length
GLchar name[bufSize]; // variable name in GLSL
GLsizei length; // name length
```

### Attributes

```
glGetProgramiv(program, GL_ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES, &count);
printf("Active Attributes: %d\n", count);

for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    glGetActiveAttrib(program, (GLuint)i, bufSize, &length, &size, &type, name);

    printf("Attribute #%d Type: %u Name: %s\n", i, type, name);
}
```

### Uniforms

```
glGetProgramiv(program, GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS, &count);
printf("Active Uniforms: %d\n", count);

for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    glGetActiveUniform(program, (GLuint)i, bufSize, &length, &size, &type, name);

    printf("Uniform #%d Type: %u Name: %s\n", i, type, name);
}
```

#### OpenGL Documentation / Variable Types

The various macros representing variable types can be found in the
docs. Such as `GL_FLOAT`, `GL_FLOAT_VEC3`, `GL_FLOAT_MAT4`, etc.

- [glGetActiveAttrib](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGetActiveAttrib.xhtml)
- [glGetActiveUniform](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGetActiveUniform.xhtml)

Comment: Perfect answer: Short, straight to the point and everything I ever wanted to know :-)

Comment: Further, there's no such thing as `GL_OBJECT_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS`, there's a `GL_OBJECT_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS_ARB` but what you actually want to use is `GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS`. *The same goes for attributes.*

Comment: I just noticed something, this only gives you the location for the first element in a uniform array. Not for all of them. What do you do if you want / need all of them?

Comment: @Makogan the whole array has this location. To set it, you then use `glUniform??v` with `count` set to the number of elements in the array. And actual number of elements of the uniform is returned by `glGetActiveUniform` in its `size` output parameter.

Answer (score 58):

There has been a change in how this sort of thing is done in OpenGL. So let's present [the old way and the new way](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Program_Introspection).

#### Old Way

Linked shaders have the concept of a number of active uniforms and active attributes (vertex shader stage inputs). These are the uniforms/attributes that are in use by that shader. The number of these (as well as quite a few other things) can be queried with [glGetProgramiv](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetProgram):

```
GLint numActiveAttribs = 0;
GLint numActiveUniforms = 0;
glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES, &numActiveAttribs);
glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS, &numActiveUniforms);
```

You can query active uniform blocks, transform feedback varyings, atomic counters, and similar things in this way.

Once you have the number of active attributes/uniforms, you can start querying information about them. To get info about an attribute, you use [`glGetActiveAttrib`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetActiveAttrib); to get info about a uniform, you use [`glGetActiveUniform`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetActiveUniform). As an example, extended from the above:

```
GLint maxAttribNameLength = 0;
glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_LENGTH​, &maxAttribNameLength);
std::vector<GLchar> nameData(maxAttribNameLength)
for(int attrib = 0; attrib < numActiveAttribs; ++attrib)
{
  GLint arraySize = 0;
  GLenum type = 0;
  GLsizei actualLength = 0;
  glGetActiveAttrib(prog, attrib, nameData.size(), &actualLength, &arraySize, &type, &nameData[0]);
  std::string name((char*)&nameData[0], actualLength - 1);
}
```

Something similar can be done for uniforms. However, the `GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORM_MAX_LENGTH​` trick can be buggy on some drivers. So I would suggest this:

```
std::vector<GLchar> nameData(256);
for(int unif = 0; unif < numActiveUniforms; ++unif)
{
  GLint arraySize = 0;
  GLenum type = 0;
  GLsizei actualLength = 0;
  glGetActiveUniform(prog, unif, nameData.size(), &actualLength, &arraySize, &type, &nameData[0]);
  std::string name((char*)&nameData[0], actualLength - 1);
}
```

Also, for uniforms, there's `glGetActiveUniforms`, which can query all of the name lengths for every uniform all at once (as well as all of the types, array sizes, strides, and other parameters).

#### New Way

This way lets you access pretty much *everything* about active variables in a successfully linked program (except for regular globals). The [ARB_program_interface_query](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/program_interface_query.txt) extension is not widely available yet, but it'll get there.

It starts with a call to [`glGetProgramInterfaceiv`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetProgramInterface), to query the number of active attributes/uniforms. Or whatever else you may want.

```
GLint numActiveAttribs = 0;
GLint numActiveUniforms = 0;
glGetProgramInterfaceiv(prog, GL_PROGRAM_INPUT, GL_ACTIVE_RESOURCES, &numActiveAttribs);
glGetProgramInterfaceiv(prog, GL_UNIFORM, GL_ACTIVE_RESOURCES, &numActiveUniforms);
```

Attributes are just vertex shader inputs; `GL_PROGRAM_INPUT` means the inputs to the first program in the program object.

You can then loop over the number of active resources, asking for info on each one in turn, from [`glGetProgramResourceiv`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetProgramResource) and [`glGetProgramResourceName`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetProgramResourceName):

```
std::vector<GLchar> nameData(256);
std::vector<GLenum> properties;
properties.push_back(GL_NAME_LENGTH​);
properties.push_back(GL_TYPE​);
properties.push_back(GL_ARRAY_SIZE​);
std::vector<GLint> values(properties.size());
for(int attrib = 0; attrib < numActiveAttribs; ++attrib)
{
  glGetProgramResourceiv(prog, GL_PROGRAM_INPUT, attrib, properties.size(),
    &properties[0], values.size(), NULL, &values[0]);

  nameData.resize(values[0]); //The length of the name.
  glGetProgramResourceName(prog, GL_PROGRAM_INPUT, attrib, nameData.size(), NULL, &nameData[0]);
  std::string name((char*)&nameData[0], nameData.size() - 1);
}
```

The exact same code would work for `GL_UNIFORM`; just swap `numActiveAttribs` with `numActiveUniforms`.

Comment: Thanks for the samples. However `actualLength - 1` should be `actualLength - 1` as `glGetActiveAttrib` returns the length of the name excluding the NULL-character.

Answer (score 20):

For anyone out there that finds this question looking to do this in WebGL, here's the WebGL equivalent:

```js
var program = gl.createProgram();
// ...attach shaders, link...

var na = gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES);
console.log(na, 'attributes');
for (var i = 0; i < na; ++i) {
  var a = gl.getActiveAttrib(program, i);
  console.log(i, a.size, a.type, a.name);
}
var nu = gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.ACTIVE_UNIFORMS);
console.log(nu, 'uniforms');
for (var i = 0; i < nu; ++i) {
  var u = gl.getActiveUniform(program, i);
  console.log(i, u.size, u.type, u.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corresponding code in python for getting the uniforms:

```
from OpenGL import GL
...
num_active_uniforms = GL.glGetProgramiv(program, GL.GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS)
for u in range(num_active_uniforms):
    name, size, type_ = GL.glGetActiveUniform(program, u)
    location = GL.glGetUniformLocation(program, name)
```

Apparently the 'new way' mentioned by Nicol Bolas does not work in python.