# Vulkan; Get list of uniforms & attribs from SPIR-V shader

Tags: c++, shader, vulkan, spir-v

Looking for a Vulkan alternative for this; [In OpenGL is there a way to get a list of all uniforms & attribs used by a shader program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/440144/5807164)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vulkan, as a general rule, does not have querying APIs for any information you have provided to the API. If you give something to the API, and you need to know something about that data, then you're expected to remember what it was.

SPIR-V contains all of the definitions of the various resources and interfaces used by a shader. And SPIR-V is a pretty well-specified format. Since you gave the SPIR-V to Vulkan, you therefore have ample opportunity to know what all of the "uniforms & attribs" in that shader are. So Vulkan has no shader querying API.

There are [several](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIRV-Reflect) [tools](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIRV-Cross) for introspecting into SPIR-V binaries to extract this kind of information. But Vulkan *itself* isn't one of them.